# Solve system of ODE $x'=Ax$ given initial value $x(0)=\xi.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the general solution for the I.V.P $x'=Ax$, $x(0)=\xi$ with
>   $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1 \\ 1&1&0\\-1&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Finding eigenvalues and generalized eigenvectors is no issue. They are $\lambda_1=0, \ \lambda_{2,3}=1$. Thus one eigenvalue is with algebraic multiplicity 2. Te corresponding eigenvectors are $v_1=[1 \ -1 \ 1]^T, \ v_2=[0 \ -1 \ 1]^T$ and $v_2^{(1)}=[-1 \ -1 \ 0]^T$. So for arbitrary initial data we have that $\xi=C_1v_1+C_2v_2+C_3v_2^{(2)}$.

In the notes, the general solution is then given as

$$x(t)=e^{At}\xi=C_1e^{\lambda_1t}v_1+C_2e^{\lambda_2t}v_2+[I+(A-\lambda_2I)t]e^{\lambda_2t}v_2^{(1)}.\tag1$$

Then they just proceed to calculate the last term $[I+(A-\lambda_2I)t]v_2^{(1)}$ and give the answer. I don't understand how they calculated $e^{At}$ in $(1)$.

I know there are a few ways calculating the exponential matrix function, one is by constructing the non-singular transformation matrix $T$ using the found eigenvectors and then finding the Jordan form and so on. But it is a bit tedious to calculate the inverse of $T$ and it contains quite ugly numbers.

---

**EDIT**: The formula for the general solution is

$$x(t)=\sum_{j=1}^s\left(e^{\lambda_jt}\left[\sum_{k=0}^{m_j-1}(A-\lambda_jI)^k\frac{t^k}{k!}\right]x^{0,j}\right), \quad m_j=\text{algebraic multiplicity.}$$

In my case $s=2$ and $m_1=1, \ m_2=2$. Thus

\begin{align}x(t)&=\sum_{j=1}^2\left(e^{\lambda_jt}\left[\sum_{k=0}^{m_j-1}(A-\lambda_jI)^k\frac{t^k}{k!}\right]x^{0,j}\right)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^2\left(e^{\lambda_jt}\left[\sum_{k=0}^{m_j-1}(A-\lambda_jI)^k\frac{t^k}{k!}\right]\right)\xi\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^2\left(e^{\lambda_jt}\left[I+(A-\lambda_2I)t\right]\right)\xi\\
&=[e^{\lambda_1t}(I+(A-\lambda_2I)t) + e^{\lambda_2t}(I+(A-\lambda_2I)t)]\xi\\
&=(e^{\lambda_1t}+e^{\lambda_2t})(A-\lambda_2I)t(C_1v_1+C_2v_2+C_3v_2^{(2)})\\
&=...
\end{align}

This does not seem correct since I get a factor $e^{\lambda_1t}(A-\lambda_2I)t$, which should not be.

Comment: They simply plugged the specific values for this system into (13) from [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3237617/265466).

Comment: Ok let me try doing that in an edit.

Comment: Looks to me like there’s a constant missing from (1), though.

Comment: Did they have a $t$ somewhere, like $[I+\color{red}{t}(A-\lambda_2 I)]$?

Comment: It's not written in the notes either, I've not made a typo I've rechecked. I thought they baked it into some other constant. Maybe it's typo in the notes. Yes, I missed the $t$! But the $C_3$ is still missing.

Comment: @amd I've edited in my own attempt. This formula feels a bit tedious to use and its easy to make mistakes. Please see my edit.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth - Please check my edit.

Comment: It would help if you copied the formula correctly. Where did the third summation come from?

Comment: I extended it because I wanted to have $$\xi=\sum_{j=1}^2x^{0,j}.$$ Anyway maybe that does not work, let me fix it. what about now?

Comment: Before continuing to bash yourself against this particular wall, verify that what you have in your notes is in fact a solution to the IVP. (It isn’t, even after adding the missing $C_3$—$x(0)\ne\xi$.)

Comment: You can’t factor $\xi$ out the way that you did in the second line since the two inner sums are **not** identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This IVP has the same structure as the one in [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3237617/265466): $A$ has one simple eigenvalue and one defective one, so aside from differences in specific values, its general solution has the same form as the one in that problem. It seems that there are two things contributing to your confusion here. The first is some apparent errors in your notes or your transcription of them here. The other is that you appear to be getting lost in the notation of the formula for the general solution to the IVP from your previous question, which might be because you haven’t quite grasped its content.

The formula from your previous question is $$x(t) = e^{tA}\xi = \sum_{j=1}^s\left(e^{\lambda_jt}\sum_{k=0}^{m_j-1}\left[(A-\lambda_jI)^k\right]x^{0,j}\right). \tag{*}$$ There’s a term in this sum for each eigenvalue with equal geometric and algebraic multiplicities and a one for each nontrivial block in the Jordan normal form of $A$. For the former, the contribution to the sum is simply $e^{\lambda_jt}x^{0,j}$, with $x^{0,j}$ a linear combination of independent eigenvectors of $\lambda_j$. For each nontrivial Jordan block, on the other hand, we have a corresponding generalized eigenvector chain of length $m_j$. That Jordan block can be decomposed into the sum $\lambda_jD+N$ of a diagonal matrix and nilpotent matrix $N$ of order $m_j$. These matrices commute, so the block’s exponential is $e^{\lambda_jt}D(I+tN+\frac{t^2}2N^2+\cdots)$, where the sum on the right is the series expansion of the exponential of $N$ and ends after $m_j$ terms. The corresponding term in (*) is then of the form $$e^{\lambda_jt}\left(I+t(A-\lambda_jI)+{t^2\over2}(A-\lambda_jI)^2+\cdots\right)x^{0,j},$$ with $m_j$ terms in the parenthesized sum.† Remember, too, that $x^{0,j}$ is the component of $\xi$ in this generalized eigenspace generated by this chain, so it’s some linear combination of the elements of the chain.

Applying this to the problem at hand, you have the simple eigenvalue $\lambda_1=0$ with $v_1=(1,-1,1)^T$ and the defective eigenvalue $\lambda_2=1$ with $v_2=(0,-1,1)^T$ and $v_2^{(1)}=(-1,-1,0)^T$. Taking the simple eigenvalue first, its contribution to the solution is simply $C_1v_1$. For the second eigenvalue, we get the term $$\begin{align} e^t(I+t(A-I))\left(C_2v_2+C_3v_2^{(1)}\right) &= C_2e^t(I+t(A-I))v_2+C_3e^t(I+t(A-I))v_2^{(1)} \\ &= C_2e^tv_2+C_3e^t(I+t(A-I))v_2^{(1)}\end{align}$$ since $(A-I)v_2=0$. Putting this together, the solution to this IVP is $$x(t) = C_1v_1 + C_2e^tv_2 + C_3e^t(I+t(A-I))v_2^{(1)}.$$ Other than a missing $C_3$, this matches the solution in your notes.

---

† The parenthesized sum is the series expansion of $\exp\left(t(A-\lambda_jI)\right)$. Only the first $m_j$ terms matter because by construction $(A-\lambda_jI)^{m_j}x^{0,j}=0$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\w}{\mathbf{w}}\newcommand{\v}{\mathbf{v}}\newcommand{\0}{\mathbf{0}}$They are using some facts about matrix exponential that actually allow you to avoid calculating $e^{At}$ itself, and instead let you calculate $e^{At}\xi$ assuming $\xi$ has been written as a linear combination of eigenvectors and generalised eigenvectors. You seem to have a big sum formula for this, but maybe it's easier to apply if you know the facts without writing it in a big summation format. The facts they are using are:

> 1) if $\v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with $A\v =\lambda \v$, then $e^{At}\v = e^{\lambda t}\v$

(this accounts for the first two terms in the right-hand side of (1)) and more generally

> 2) if $\w_1$ is a generalised eigenvector for eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ and we have a Jordan chain $$\w_1 \xrightarrow{A-\lambda I} \w_2\xrightarrow{A-\lambda I}\w_3\xrightarrow{A-\lambda I}\cdots \xrightarrow{A-\lambda I}\w_k  \xrightarrow{A-\lambda I}\mathbf{0},$$ then $$e^{At}\w_1 = e^{\lambda t}\left(\w_1+t\w_2 + \frac{t^2}{2!}\w_3+\cdots + \frac{t^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\w_{k-1}\right).$$

Note that above, $k$ is the length of the Jordan chain if you don't count $\0$ in the chain. For your example, $v_2^{(1)}$ is a generalised eigenvector for eigenvalue $\lambda_2$ with a chain of length $k=2$, i.e. $v_2^{(1)}\xrightarrow{A-\lambda_2 I} a\xrightarrow{A-\lambda_2 I} \0$, where $a=(A-\lambda _2 I)v_2^{(1)}$. Hence by the second fact above, we have

$$
e^{At}v_2^{(1)} = e^{\lambda_2 t}\left( v_2^{(1)} + ta\right) \quad (\text{stop at the last non-zero vector of the Jordan chain}).
$$

If you now use $a = (A-\lambda_2 I)v_2^{(1)}$, you should be able to arrive at the formula they had, i.e. $e^{At}v_2^{(1)} = e^{\lambda_2 t}\left(I + (A-\lambda_2 I)\right)v_2^{(1)}$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on 2)? I don't understand how you expanded $e^{At}\mathbf{w}_1.$

Comment: $\newcommand{\w}{\mathbf{w}}$This is a result that you can prove by using the facts that $e^{At} = e^{\lambda t}e^{(A-\lambda I)t}$, $e^{(A-\lambda I)t} = I + t(A-\lambda I) +\frac{t^2}{2!}(A-\lambda I)^2+ \cdots$, and (from the Jordan chain) $(A-\lambda I)\w_1= \w_2, (A-\lambda I)^2 \w_1 = \w_3,\ldots, (A-\lambda I)^{k-1}\w_1 = \w_k$ and $(A-\lambda I)^j \w_1 =\mathbf{0}$ for all $j\ge k$.